# Set a variable in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, window, namespaces

Is it possible to create an Iframe using `document.createElement("iframe");` and then set a variable in the iframe's window object such as a namespace?

I have tried doing something like this:

```
var Namespace = {}; 
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); 
iframe.src = "page.html"; 
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var iwin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.defaultView; 
iwin.Namespace = Namespace;
```

But in page.html I try to log `Namespace` and it throws an undefined error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same-origin policy is probably blocking you from doing this. This can also happen in some browsers if both pages use a file:// uri scheme.

If the iframe and the outer windows will be using the same domain, this problem should go away once your code is on a server. Try serving it from localhost using apache to check, or test it with google chrome with same-origin policy disabled as per this post:

[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy)

On the other hand, if the iframe needs to be at a different domain, or this needs to work with the file:// uri scheme, you'll need to use some kind of workaround.

One way to pass data into an iframe at another domain is via a fragment identifier in the iframe element's src attribute, which will be visible in the iframe window's 'location' object's 'hash' property; for example:

Outer page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head></head><body>
<script>
  var Namespace = {foo:1, bar:2}; 
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); 
  iframe.src = "frame.html#" + JSON.stringify(Namespace);
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
</script>
</body></html>
```

Inner page "frame.html":

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head></head><body>
<a href="#" onclick="alert(location.hash.substring(1))">click me</a>
</body></html>
```

Comment: My hero; thank you very much. Didn't know same origin applied to file://

Answer (score 0):

document.appendChild(iframe);

I'm pretty sure you need to add the node you created to the DOM.